# Library to get a String to behave like in 1.9 in 1.8

Tags: ruby, encoding

Im looking for a lib that will warp my strings so they behave more like 1.9 so i can use them more easily in a 1.8/1.9 project e.g.

```
Lib.new("ääq").size == 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did it myself...

```
gem install string19
String19('áßð').size == 3
String19('áßð').index('ð') == 2
```

etc.
not all methods supported, but easy to add more

Answer (score 2):

James Gray wrote a series of good articles about dealing with Unicode and multi-byte characters that are good reading. In particular "[The $KCODE Variable and jcode Library](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/the_kcode_variable_and_jcode_library)" and "[Getting Code Ready for Ruby 1.9](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/getting_code_ready_for_ruby_19) " will help a lot.

Basically, you can add:

```
$KCODE = 'U'
```

to the top of your source file and inherit some new functionality for dealing with multibyte characters.